# What software can I use to auto generate class diagrams in PHP?

Tags: php

I have some source code and I would like to auto generate class diagrams in PHP.
What software can I use to do this?

**Duplicate**

- [PHP UML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)
- [UML tool for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704957/uml-tool-for-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP UML Generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen can do class diagrams, too (if what I'm thinking of are "class diagrams" :) ).

Answer (score 0):

[Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look at [Instant Reverse](http://resource.visual-paradigm.com/tips_and_tricks/code_engineering/reverse_engineering_php_source_by_instant_reverse.html)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for people who visits stackoverflow for finding answers to their queries.

http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_UML/

I have not evaluated PHP UML package thoroughly, but It should satisfy the need of small to medium size project.