# generating class diagrams for php projects ( codeigniter framework)

Tags: php, codeigniter, uml, class-diagram

I'm developing a system using **Codeigniter**, and it's nearly completion, i didn't went for class diagrams first because it was hard to decide, so i straight away did coding and now i want to draw class diagrams for my project. do you guys know about a tool that i can use for generating class diagrams for my project?

Comment: A new release is planed to support PHP >= 7.1: https://github.com/llaville/umlwriter. I did not try it so far, but will do it after the release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw them manually (ie. don't want reverse engineering to generate uml from your PHP source), then [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) might be useful (if you're using Windows that is, but since you don't mention it I assume you do).

BTW The following question might be helpful too : [PHP UML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)

Comment: Hi wimvds,

i want to revese engineer and generate the class diagrams, do you know any solutions?

Comment: See my edit :p. The first two answers to that question already mention 2 ways to go about it. The first just generates XMI files for just about any UML tool, [BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/) is a complete package that should support PHP reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

[phUML](https://github.com/jakobwesthoff/phuml) is the best tool I have encountered and only worked for me. You can easily generate a class diagram from your existing code.

Navigate to the folder and try the below command to generate the class diagram on linux

```
./phuml -r /var/www/my_project -graphviz -createAssociations false -neato out.png
```

> phUML is fully automatic UML class diagramm generator written PHP. It
>   is capable of parsing any PHP5 object oriented source code and create
>   an appropriate image representation of the oo structure based on the
>   UML specification.

More info

```
./phuml --help
```