# Is there any visual tool for design and generate code of PHP classes?

Tags: php, code-generation, class-design

I know that general, language agnostic design can be done with any of UML tools but is there anything made just for PHP (or with PHP as one of optional choices)? For now I use NClass, it's nice and easy to use but it is designed for C# so I have to use syntax of this language (types for method's arguments, etc.).

I googled the web but I didn't noticed anything made with PHP syntax in mind so I ask here. It would also be great not to find out that some plugin for Visual Studio or Eclipse is the answer :) Not that I'm against these products but something lighter and separated from huge IDE would be nice to have in my toolkit.

**EDIT**: I just downloaded ArgoUML because it suppose to have PHP support, so I check it out but let that fact not discourage you, I'm still waiting for your tips :)

**EDIT2**: Little feature I also seek in tool in question is assistance for code issues like adding interface methods to a class implementing that interface, for example. ArgoUML does not have such feature or I just didn't not found it yet.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect 8 trial and it seems just do what I need and the way I need it (nice and easy, with details if I need them and with useful defaults when I just want to draw my diagrams). Code generation covers many languages and PHP is one of them and it works without problems and code is nice and clean, just what I wanted as a base for coding phase after thinking phase :)

So, as for now I think I found my tool (it's big and powerful but seems pretty light for its enterprise look). I keep this question open for some time, maybe someone will want to add some useful info on that matter.

Answer (score 1):

check out this website:
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/class/90.html

It has lots of php editors and class generators..

hope it helps
regards

Answer (score 0):

see this post with answers special on  [bouml](http://bouml.free.fr/)

[PHP UML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)

Comment: first impression after few minutes of checking out: not very user friendly or intuitive but I will give it another try at home

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) for a while now, and I find it very intuitive to use, great product!

Comment: I believe that's great tool but it's price is a little outside of my comfort area, buying tools for $1300 just for my personal projects seems... disturbing :)

Comment: @grapkulec: Damn.. I see they have changed their lineup.. I have an older version which had cost me about $300 (still not free of course), that has the php code generation!

Answer (score 0):

AtomWeaver is a general-purpose code generator. It is not limited to any set of output languages, so you can include your own. The hard part is that you have to start from scratch as no pre-made libraries are available as of today. The good part is that you can generate code just the way you need/want.

http://www.atomweaver.com for the generator;
http://www.abse.info for the modeling/generation paradigm it implements (ABSE)