# Is there a round-trip software for PHP programmers out there?

Tags: php, sql, creation

I search for a round-trip programming solution which does generate PHP and SQL code from a UML Model

It sould also include state and activity diagrams which were compiled into PHP/SQL.

Or does someone know some software who offers the possibility to create my own PHP / UML interpreter?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) has code creation from UML to PHP5

Also see

- http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/provides/codedbeng.jsp (commercial)
- [PHP UML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Dia` has plugins to convert class diagrams into PHP classes