# Object browser for PHP

Tags: php, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

I want to browse huge amounts of code written in PHP and it would be useful to have a graphical representation of various classes and their methods.

Do you know of (free) tools making this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out http://bouml.free.fr/screenshots.html

Here's other references: [PHP UML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)

Answer (score 1):

Try [phpOBrowser](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/developer/gogogadgetscott-4565.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use xDebug you can get visibility of all the objects currently in use at run-time.

I use NetBeans as my dev environment, and xDebug is built into that, so I can step through my code and browse the objects at any point while the code is running.

I don't know if that's the answer you're looking for, but it is a very useful way to see see exactly what's happening with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that let's you paste serialized PHP and displays it in a treeview: https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-object-browser