# Software which makes UML diagrams from PHP scripts

Tags: php, uml

I heard of software which can turn UML diagrams into different languages, like PHP, C++, etc.
But I can't find a tool which makes UML diagrams from PHP code. 
Is there any? If not, why?!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP UML Generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator) and [some others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+to+uml)

Answer (score 1):

One of these tools is called ArgoUML http://argouml.tigris.org/.

PHP is included in the default-package since version 0.13.2 (March 2003).

If you're interested in some other languages like JavaScript, Python you can download a plugin on the project-homepage.

You can also create a uml-diagram out of your existing sourcecode. But I'm sorry - this is not avaiable for php-files.