# Software to generate PHP classes from UML Class Diagram

Tags: php, macos, class, object, uml

Looking for some Mac software that will enable me to auto-generate PHP classes from a UML class diagram.

Does anything like this exist?

Thanks

Comment: see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759273/creating-umls-for-php-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enterprise Architect by Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html) provides something like this. It allows you to generate class definitions from UML diagrams.

I've never used it with PHP before, only with C#, and I've always been better off generating the code myself. It adds a lot of code that's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the corresponding PHP classes, but this [UMLtoPHP online code-generation service](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml2php-full-code-generation-php-applications) will generate the doctrine YAML model corresponding to the UML class diagram. Of course, the benefit is that this definition is enough to automatically generate a full-fledged CRUD application when using a framework like symfony

Comment: Btw, the services accepts as input UML models defined with a variety of UML tools including free ones like ArgoUML

Answer (score 0):

My company BITPlan created UML2PHP in 2003 - the 2008 version is still available via:
http://www.uml2php.com/com/bitplan/web/uml2php/index.php