# reverse engineer eclipse-PDT-php->UML

Tags: php, uml, eclipse-pdt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP UML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)

Hi,

I wonder if it's even possible to reverse engineering some PHP (PDT) code back to an UML  class diagram ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator) topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik there is no Eclipse plugin that converts PHP to UML, but you could use an [external tool](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_own_external_tools%3F), e.g. [phpuml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator/591527#591527).