# Generate class diagrams from PHP classes automatically?

Tags: php, zend-framework, uml, zend-studio, class-diagram

I have build a web application in Zend Framework and now desperately need a tool/plugin which can generate class diagram from all of my Zend Controllers (Classes).

I uses Zend Studio and Eclipse so if you know any plugin which does the job then please do let me know.

All help and comments are really appreciated.

Many Thanks
Vishal

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP UML Generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[autodia](http://www.aarontrevena.co.uk/opensource/autodia/) is easy to use if a bit basic. It handles a range of languages and makes a nice job of mySQL as well.

see also [PHP UML Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator)