# php uml reverse engineering

Tags: php, uml, reverse-engineering, diagram

I'm strugglying with UML diagrams as I just need to draw diagram to visualize better the dozen of classes I've created : I'm lost with these classes every time I come back from a break. So I'd need to draw them back from sources.

I know it's not a real new topic ([for example this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator/591527#591527)) but I spent the whole night on that w/o finding the right answer to my point :

I "only" need :

- to draw uml diagrams from my php5 source code,
- this tool to be fully integrated into Eclipse (helios pdt),
- this tool under EPL/GPL licence,
- optional, this tool being able to do the reverse later on, e.g. building php sources from diagram,

Is there an appropriate tool to achieve (only) this ? What's the best recommendation to start with a simple uml tool ?

Notes :
I have seen this [MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility list](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility) but I can't try all the EPL licenced one by one.

I've tried using bouml, uml2 and myeclipseUML, but none looks really adapted to my need or I did not understand them :
- [bouml](http://bouml.free.fr/index.html) is not Eclipse integrated and not maintained anymore,
(I understand it can be run as external eclipse tool),
- [UML2 SDK](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html#install) looks "only" java focused,
- [MyEclipse UML2 plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-2-plugin-eclipse) could not read the [phpuml](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-uml.command-line.php) xmi file I created using *pear* in command line. Despite it looks the more appropriate to my need. EDIT: this tool looks also java focused.

EDIT:
[here is the best UML tool list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ArgoUML in the past with success. It's cross platform too.
http://argouml.tigris.org/

Comment: Thx I have given it a try but I must be too stupid as it looks needing longer than taking my pencil to obtain these @%$ diagrams. Despite it looks like very promising on paper but could not use it properly without further support.